# Can I pass anything other than a file to SimpleXmlIterator?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, multidimensional-array, simplexml

I am trying to convert an XML string into and array. SimpleXmlIterator only accepts a path to a file as a parameter. Is there any way I can pass a string instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

```
SimpleXMLIterator::__construct ( string $data [, int $options [, bool $data_is_url [, string $ns [, bool $is_prefix ]]]] )
```

Therefore this loads a string:

```
$it = new SimpleXMLIterator ($xml_string);
```

This loads a file:

```
$it = new SimpleXMLIterator ($xml_filename, 0, true);
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The [ctor signature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) is

```
SimpleXMLIterator::__construct ( 
    string $data [, 
        int $options [, 
            bool $data_is_url [, 
                string $ns [, 
                    bool $is_prefix ]]]] )
```

so you should be able to pass in both: a string and a file by changing `$data_is_url`:

> By default, data_is_url is FALSE. Use TRUE to specify that data is a path or URL to an XML document instead of string data.

Also, see the [first user-contributed comment in the PHP Manual for `SimpleXmlIterator` for an example how to turn XML into an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmliterator.php). The example uses a file, but you should have no problems adapting this to your needs know.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you see that?  [`SimpleXMLIterator`](https://www.php.net/simplexmliterator) accepts a string as XML data to the [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) by default...  You can pass it a filename in the first parameter by setting the third parameter to `true`, but it defaults to `false`...

And `asXml()` has an optional `$filename` parameter, but you can leave it off if you want and it'll return a string...